# Save geany 'status' logs to file?

Tags: 16.04, geany

The content of the status tab in geany:

[image]

(logs your activity). I would like to append that to a file automatically. Ideally the file would start empty and each new item on this tab would be appended to it. Preferably, the file's name should be a random string (so it doesn't overwrite an existing one).

Is there a way? What is the way?

Comment: @DKBose: yes: it's exactly what I want. Is there a way to have this always on the background automatically?